# JQuery detect dropdown selection change and subsequent function to be called

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdown selection named "A" and "B"
I would like to detect change in selection of "A", and on change of selection, the selection of "B" to be changed into value "1"(assuming parent div for "B" is "agent")

Using jquery
I have no idea of the jquery to use at all pls kindly suggest answer tq

```
<div id="Person"><option value="1">1<option><option value="2">2<option></div>
<div id="Agent"><option value="1">1<option><option value="2">2<option></div>
```

Comment: shouldn't `<div id="Person">` this be `<select id="Person">`

Comment: @ArunPJohny the container doesn't really matters, it depends on how you call the function that it?am i right

Answer (score 1):

`option` elements must be descendants of `select` so change your markup to

```
<select id="Person">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="Agent">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

then use the [change event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to reset the value of `#Agent`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#Person').change(function () {
        $('#Agent').val(1)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4r4bT/)

Comment: sadly my value is "wpcf-fields-select-option-87f1c81ae737751c612c2c19046a3819-1" .val won't work on that

Comment: @CheongDMunPong try `$('#Agent').val('wpcf-fields-select-option-87f1c81ae737751c612c2c19046a3819-1')`

Comment: thank you so much worked like a charm, but though  can't make my work perfect, due to some platform problem, thank you

Comment: hi, would be great if you can help me if to change the select to disabled, under the above condition instead of changing the value

Comment: under which condition?

Comment: @CheongDMunPong change `$('#Agent').val(1)` to `$('#Agent').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: what if i want to change the value to 1 then followed by 2?

Comment: how do you know which value to set

Comment: @CheongDMunPong no it sets the value to 2

Comment: will it set the value to 1 first then followed by 2?

Comment: because of this platform i using, i can set conditional display group according to the value chosen, so initially i tried to set the value when #agent changed, but it doesn't help, so now i think i should try the :focus instead? what do you think? worth a try? if so please help me with the code, change of focus to value 1 instead of changing the value, thank you very much

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4r4bT/5/ Please kindly see my revision were i want to change the value first then the focus,i have tested it, changing value is fine, but the focus im not sure is it working that way

Answer (score 0):

There is an onchange function for dropdown list selection. You can call a function using this attribute.

```
    <select id="a" onchange="changeB">
     </select>
```

I am answering this from my phone so i am not able to provide you a demo.
Google about onchange and you will be able to tackle your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is an onchange event in select element.

In A's onchange event handler change B's option select attribute.

```
<select id="A">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
<select id="B">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>

$('#A').change(function() {
  // Get selected item in A
  var index = $(this).find("option:selected").index();

  // Set the corresponding item in B
  $("#B option").get(index).selected = true;
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hctLu/)